# rails - ActionMailer URL for dev versus prod

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby-on-rails-3, actionmailer

I've been building an app locally and all the mailers used the URL 0.0.0.0:3000 which is what I wanted...

Now I just pushed to heroku, and the URLs didn't update to the product mailer URL. Did I set this up correctly?

/config/environments/production.rb

```
    config.action_mailer.default_url_options = { :host => 'mynewapp.heroku.com' }
```

/config/initializers/setup_mail.rb

```
ActionMailer::Base.smtp_settings = {
  :address              => "smtp.sendgrid.net",
  :port                 => "25",
  :authentication       => "plain",
  :domain               => "xxxxxxx.com",
  :user_name            => "xxxx@xxxxxx.com",
  :password             => "xxxxxxxxxxxxx"
}

# The to field is then changed so that the email is sent to
ActionMailer::Base.default_url_options[:host] = "0.0.0.0:3000"
Mail.register_interceptor(DevelopmentMailInterceptor) if Rails.env.development?
```

yet all the URLs are still 0.0.0.0:3000 is there some setting I need to set when I push to heroku to specific that rails is in production mode? Or did I mess something up above?

Thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Put this line:

```
ActionMailer::Base.default_url_options[:host] = "0.0.0.0:3000"
```

in *config/environments/development.rb*, and also in *config/environments/production.rb*, but modify it in the latter to be the appropriate URL.

By putting it in an initializer you're setting it up for all environments, which is incorrect.

Answer (score 0):

Add this line to your `Gemfile` :

```
gem "action_mailer_auto_url_options"
```

and URLs will be mapped correctly automatically.